# Should I say "To secure" or "To securing?"

Tags: gerunds

This use of continuous always gets me confused, and I stumbled on it all the time.

> *Consumers are increasingly turning to Brokers as the ‘easiest route’ **to securing** a mortgage.* (Written by a native English speaker)
>
> *Consumers are increasingly turning to Brokers as the ‘easiest route’ **to secure** a mortgage.* (The way I would have written it)

Grammarly tells me both previous sentences are correct.
Would I really be correct? If so, could someone tell me how to choose between both?
I'm pretty sure the same would apply to other verbs.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical and idiomatic. The first uses an ing-clause as the prepositional complement (that is, 'to' is the preposition; compare 'the beginner's guide to building pyramids'), while the second sentence uses a to-infinitival complement (compare 'the easiest way to succeed').

[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=route+to+secure+a%2Croute+to+securing+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croute%20to%20secure%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Croute%20to%20securing%20a%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Croute%20to%20secure%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Croute%20to%20securing%20a%3B%2Cc0) for 'route to secure a' / 'route to securing a' show that both are used (adding the indefinite article ensures 'secure' is the verb):

[image]

and strongly suggest that the ing-clause is now the favoured choice after 'route [to]'. This may not be the same for 'way to' and other similar expressions.

Comment: I find it interesting that the near-synonymous [*quickest **way** to secure / securing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=route+to+secure+a%2Croute+to+securing+a%2Cway+to+secure+a%2Cway+to+securing+a&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croute%20to%20secure%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Croute%20to%20securing%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cway%20to%20secure%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cway%20to%20securing%20a%3B%2Cc0) [something]* hasn't apparently experienced this same shift in favour of the gerund/continuous form.

Comment: 'A way to [do something]' is a dead metaphor now, crystallised. I find 'a route to ...' more readily brings the literal sense to mind, with prepositional _to_.